# About Nodejs global var

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var articleFinish;
  async.series({
    one: function(callback) {
      async.eachOf(set, function(tags, index, callback) {
        Article.findById(articleId).exec(function(err, article) {
          article.weibos[2].text = 'aa'; //success
          article.weibos[2].tags = 'aaa'; //success
          article.weibos[index].text = tags; //can't set value for next 'article'
          article.weibos[index].tags = tags; //can't set value for next 'article'
          articleFinish = article;
          callback();
        });
      }, function(err) {
        if (err) console.error(err.message);
        callback(null, 3);
      });
    },
    two: function(callback) {
      Article.findById(articleId).exec(function(err, article) {
        article = articleFinish;//can't get value when use the last two statement.
        article.save(function(err) {});
      });
    }
  }, function(err, results) {
    res.send(results);
  });
```

I want to set the last `article`'s value by a global var.

What should I do?

Comment: Don't use global variables. Pass your results to the callback.

Comment: Do you want to set the global `articleFinish` or the local `article` variable?